# POD with mysql and wordpress

Tags: kubernetes

I'am tryng to learn K8S and I have followed some tutorial but I have an Issue.
How can I connect my wordpress to my mysql db ?

A random secret is generated by mysql for root and first connection.
I have used this manifest but I have error Error establishing a database 
connection

Can you tell how to connect to my mysql server to recover the random secret or any solution to understand and resolve my issue please ?

Thanks a lot

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: wp-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: wordpress-ct
    image: wordpress
    env:
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
      value: mysqlpwd
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
      value: 127.0.0.1
  - name: mysql-ct
    image: mysql
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: mysqlpwd
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumes:
  - name: data
    emptyDir: {}



kubectl get all
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/debug        1/1     Running   13         37h
pod/new-wp-pod   2/2     Running   0          7s
pod/www          1/1     Running   0          37h
```

-

kubectl port-forward pod/new-wp-pod 8080:80

-

Brower error http://localhost:8080/

```
error Error establishing a database 
connection
```

-

```
root@new-wp-pod:/var/www/html# ls
index.php        wp-admin              wp-config.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-settings.php
license.txt      wp-blog-header.php    wp-content     wp-load.php        wp-signup.php
readme.html      wp-comments-post.php  wp-cron.php    wp-login.php       wp-trackback.php
wp-activate.php  wp-config-sample.php  wp-includes    wp-mail.php        xmlrpc.php
root@new-wp-pod:/var/www/html# cat wp-config.php
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'mysqlpwd');

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         '8791830dd9fc85ced9dd9ff993363f1bae2add6f');
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '71a37b78a9e54ff5256cccc843645afaf4d4baac');
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '108ec9ab01eb7280bf5e48d8982e115e06560dc5');
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        '7bc243bf7ed23389bf96dce94b41018bb139aeec');
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        '55e44dc4f33ead449ba738f7d01f8d79297b74f6');
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '7930012aeff11ba89585a09de8237f8bf80b6c93');
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '2698989a788b7b94b3f211077bf2c77ce3c51f60');
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'acd8bda316b0f92e664b0c451163af562945ae48');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

// If we're behind a proxy server and using HTTPS, we need to alert Wordpress of that fact
// see also http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL#Using_a_Reverse_Proxy
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );



     kubectl describe po/wp-pod
Name:         wp-pod
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         k8snode1/192.168.1.16
Start Time:   Mon, 09 Sep 2019 02:04:14 -0400
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.1.16
Containers:
  wordpress-ct:
    Container ID:   docker://b20c92ac7c67cdb707c0623f080aa1e406d32ff762e292e866fac1a93a4aa8c4
    Image:          wordpress
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://wordpress@sha256:2d1ced84d8bfa187d69479cec36fc57824a9d22125050ffd55fe7dbc92bd473c
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 09 Sep 2019 02:04:17 -0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:  mysqlpwd
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:      127.0.0.1
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-j9sjf (ro)
  mysql-ct:
    Container ID:   docker://f0b4a418c5feb95ad277d434bf8f0a93d9ccd5fbff4236e5feac2dda06465dc9
    Image:          mysql
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mysql@sha256:01cf53f2538aa805bda591d83f107c394adca8d31f98eacd3654e282dada3193
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 09 Sep 2019 02:04:19 -0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  mysqlpwd
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-j9sjf (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  default-token-j9sjf:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-j9sjf
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  2m52s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/wp-pod to k8snode1
  Normal  Pulling    2m51s  kubelet, k8snode1  Pulling image "wordpress"
  Normal  Pulled     2m49s  kubelet, k8snode1  Successfully pulled image "wordpress"
  Normal  Created    2m49s  kubelet, k8snode1  Created container wordpress-ct
  Normal  Started    2m49s  kubelet, k8snode1  Started container wordpress-ct
  Normal  Pulling    2m49s  kubelet, k8snode1  Pulling image "mysql"
  Normal  Pulled     2m48s  kubelet, k8snode1  Successfully pulled image "mysql"
  Normal  Created    2m47s  kubelet, k8snode1  Created container mysql-ct
  Normal  Started    2m47s  kubelet, k8snode1  Started container mysql-ct
```

-

```
kubectl logs -f new-wp-pod -c mysql-ct
Error from server (NotFound): pods "new-wp-pod" not found
[rbo@K8SMaster ~]$ kubectl logs -f new-wp-pod -c ^C
[rbo@K8SMaster ~]$ kubectl logs -f wp-pod -c mysql-ct
Initializing database
2019-09-09T06:04:19.288516Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-09-09T06:04:19.288579Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) initializing of server in progress as process 28
2019-09-09T06:04:20.767998Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2019-09-09T06:04:21.694368Z 0 [System] [MY-013170] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) initializing of server has completed
Database initialized
MySQL init process in progress...
2019-09-09T06:04:23.309354Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-09-09T06:04:23.309459Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 80
2019-09-09T06:04:23.659349Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-09-09T06:04:23.661058Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-09-09T06:04:23.674473Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-09-09T06:04:23.834817Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.

2019-09-09T06:04:28.044068Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2019-09-09T06:04:28.367849Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-09-09T06:04:28.367929Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1
2019-09-09T06:04:28.671834Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-09-09T06:04:28.673563Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-09-09T06:04:28.687554Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-09-09T06:04:28.876157Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Comment: I have deleted and recreated a new pod that why the name of the pod for command kubectl logs and kubectl describe changed

Comment: You should _always_ run your application and database in separate deployments/statefulsets.  (As you've shown it you have to delete your database to upgrade your application code.)  Randomly generate your own password and store it in a Kubernetes secret.

Answer (score 1):

your yaml seems correct and I have tried one myself to check if it works and it does. Can you run "kubectl describe pod new-wp-pod..." and also "kubectl logs -f new-wp-pod -c mysql-ct"? I am thinking your mysql pod is not running.

If you want to debug further you could add another container and do a "telnet localhost 3306" to check mysql is running. Also a netstat -tlpn could help.

```
      - name: "container-1"
        image: alpine
        args:
          - "sleep"
          - "1000"
```

However, given that you want to run two containers I would recommend using different deployments and allow them to be resolved via kubernetes services. The following two yamls should do the job.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    mojix.service: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3306"
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    mojix.service: mysql
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    mojix.service: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      mojix.service: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        mojix.service: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "mysql"
        image: mysql
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: "root"
          - name: MYSQL_DB
            value: "test"
      hostname: mysql
      restartPolicy: Always
```

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    mojix.service: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8000"
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    mojix.service: wordpress
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    mojix.service: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      mojix.service: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        mojix.service: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "wordpress-ct"
        image: wordpress
        env:
          - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
            value: "root"
          - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
            value: "mysql"
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. mysql container is running, thanks for sharing me your manifest.I would like to find where come from my issue, I think it will help me to undertand in futur this error. I have edited my post with result of command you have posted.

Comment: I have launch the pod but when I do my forward to 8080:8000  
Should I open port on master and node ? `kubectl port-forward wordpress-55fb4ffcf5-n4wnx  8080:8000
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8000
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8000
Handling connection for 8080
E0909 04:24:42.683816   16717 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 8000: error forwarding port 8000 to pod ec401e4b7db1ff9c88cd0e042e90b78c42d33f90a9386e3d7342fdf20dfb5295, uid : exit status 1: 2019/09/09 04:24:42 socat[5872] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8000, 16): Connection refused`

Comment: First, given the logs mysql, it seems like it started. I would add another container with the alpine image and check the port 3306 is open. Otherwise you could telnet to localhost 3306 to check the database is up. That will basically tell you whether the error is infrastructure or the wordpress container.

Comment: With respect to the forwarding. Yes, you will have to add a firewall rule to allow connections. What k8s cluster are you using? cloud provider? self-hosted?

Comment: I am using self VM on my proxmox server